# Como instalar servidor PHP com componentes separados

Tags: php, mysql

Uma dúvida besta mas pesquisei aqui e não encontrei nada. Já tenho o MySQL rodando no meu computador, como instalo o PHP sem instalar EasyPHP, Xampp? Porque geralmente esses programas já trazem o MySQL junto. Como faço?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O EasyPHP, Xampp, Wamp não são "coisas oficiais" do PHP, eles são "facilitadores" para a instalação de softwares já existentes, ou seja, instalar usando Xampp ou EasyPHP são apenas alternativas as "instalações oficiais".

No caso do Wamp:

- **W**indows
- **A**pache que é o servidor HTTP
- **M**ysql que é o banco de dados
- **P**HP que é uma linguagem para desenvolver aplicações web

> As iniciais formam a palavra Wamp

Existem outros tipos, como por exemplo o WnMP:

- **W**indows
- **N**ginx que é o servidor HTTP
- **M**ariaDB que é o banco de dados
- **P**HP que é uma linguagem para desenvolver aplicações web

> As iniciais formam a palavra WnMP

Em outras palavras, é *totalmente possível* instalar PHP em uma máquina sem instalar Mysql, basta você baixar:

- [Download do PHP](http://php.net/downloads.php)
- [Download do Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi)

E seguir este tutorial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/install.windows.apache2.php

Comment: Valeu cara!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

O PHP, a partir da versão 5.4, traz um servidor web nativo. Não é necessário sintalar Apache ou Nginx.

Veja mais sobre ele aqui: http://rberaldo.com.br/como-usar-o-servidor-nativo-do-php-5-4/

Basta baixar o PHP do site oficial (http://php.net) e já terá tudo que precisa