# PHP no linux ou windows

Tags: php, linux, windows, framework

**Explicação:**

Eu sei que é uma pergunta polêmica, mas eu não sou senhor idoso das programações e tenho conhecimentos de linux, mas nunca o escolhi porque eu utilizo C# de vez em quando e na minha faculdade eles são pró-microsoft. Então os trabalhos em sua maioria é no Windows e acho que Dual-boot não faz bem pro meu PC que não parece que foi feito pra isso.

**Pergunta:**

A minha linguagem de programação efetiva é o PHP e vejo frameworks que abusam mais do Linux do que o Windows em si, devo então me render e comprar um notebook linux ou existem profissionais sêniores que gostam do Windows pra mexer com Linux?

Comment: um comentário  nada a ver mas , troque de faculdade.. Não tenho nada contra MS, pelo contrário, uso MS como ferramenta primária, mas a nível de faculdade, vc deveria estar num ambiente mais aberto onde não ficam "presos" a uma marca ou produto. A faculdade onde está só vai formar gente "engessada tecnologicamente"...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> E que mito é esse que só os idosos da programação usam linux? Não acredite em tudo que te contam :)

O PHP é uma linguagem multi-plataforma, ou seja basta ter o PHP instalado para a versão do sistema escolhido e vai funcionar.

As APIs do PHP são todas compatíveis com qualquer sistema operacional (tendo raras funções que não trabalham no Solaris (um outro sistema operacional) e poucas funções com vagas diferenças entre os sistemas, se usadas de modo avançado geralmente.

Eu nunca vi isso de o PHP "abusar do linux", quem te contou isso provavelmente estava enganado.

A única coisa que vai mudar de Windows para Linux/Unix para o PHP:

> Note que para se referenciar ao sistemas semelhantes ao linux ou unix podemos usar o termo `*nix` ou o termo `like-unix` (muito usado pelos gringos)

- Divisão de pastas no Windows usa `\`  e no *nix usa `/`, no entanto se usar apenas `/` vai funcionar em ambos sistemas
- *nix tem permissões de pasta para escrita, leitura e execução o Windows não
- A arquitetura de pastas (não influencia muito, pois geralmente os scripts PHP ficam em uma pasta só)
- *nix **geralmente** é case-sensitive, ou seja se tiver um arquivo com o nome assim `Foo.txt` e usar a função `is_file('foo.txt')`, irá retornar `false`, no entanto no Windows é case-insensitive, ou seja irá retornar `true`, então só deve ter cuidado no windows, pois isto pode causar problemas se o servidor de produção for *nix.

Então a escolha do ambiente pouco faz diferença para o PHP e as raras incompatibilidades geralmente são resolvidas com outras funções da API.

### Resumindo:

Não necessita comprar um computador com Linux basta entender as diferenças de ambos tipos de sistemas (arquitetura de pastas principalmente)

### Instalar o PHP

- [Como instalar servidor PHP com componentes separados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45564/3635)
- [Wamp <sup>windows</sup>](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download)
- [Xampp <sup>windows/linux/macosx</sup>](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/download.html)

### Extras

- O PHP pode rodar como servidor, porém ele não é um servidor completo e é recomendavel apenas para o ambiente de desenvolvimento, ele só funciona como servidor [stand-alone](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), para funcionar como servidor "completo" é necessário baixar os softwares separadamente como o mysql e apache, mas existem caminhos mais fáceis, como está escrito acima.
- O significado Wamp seria Windows Apache, Mysql e PHP, assim como Xampp significa Apache, Mysql, Php e Perl (o X indica multi-plataforma) e Lamp seria Linux, apache, mysql e PHP.
- Além do Apache existem outros servidores alternativos como o [Nginx](http://nginx.org) e o [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net)
- Linux não é um sistema operacional, ele é o núcleo ou seja um sistema Linux na verdade é um sistema baseado em Linux apenas, acredito que todas distros Linux hoje rodem com `linux-3.*` ou `linux-4`.
- Unix também não é um sistema, mas sim um núcleo, que é usado por muitos sistemas (modificado é claro), como MacOSX e a família BSD.
- Linux e Unix apesar de usarem uma estrutura de pastas parecidas e terem respostas parecidas ao "alto-nível", não são um evolução do outro e nem "primos", são núcleos distintos, tanto que GNU (O nome formal do Linux seria GNU/Linux) significaria algo como ***G***NU is **N**ot **U**nix (Português: GNU Não é Unix)
- O equivalente deles no Windows seria o núcleo **Windows NT**.

  **Leia mais em:** [Kernel_(operating_system)<sup>en</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system))
- O `C#` pode rodar em ambientes *nix, usando o [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/), além do C# há outras linguagens suportadas e por incrível que pareça alguns dos projetos que mantem suporte para estas linguagens conseguem suportar o "Windows" também.

  Linguagens suportadas <sup>([linguagens no Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/))</sup>:

  - C#, F#, Java, Scala, Doo, Nemerle, VisualBasic.NET, Python (há duas opções PythonNet e IronPython), JavaScript (IronJS), Oberon, PHP, Object Pascal, Lua, Cobra

  Outras linguagens:

  - Component Pascal, Delta Forth, DotLisp, #Smalltalk

  Linguagens suportadas mas não mantidas:

  - C, Ruby e Ada
- O C# também pode rodar em ambientes linux e macOS usando o *.NET Core*, sendo este **oficial da Microsoft** (lançado em Junho de 2016), mais detalhes em: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/about

Answer (score 4):

Vou endereçar os tópicos por partes:

## Windows vs UNIX para desenvolvimento de aplicações

Existe basicamente dois tipos de sistemas operacionais em uso em massa no mundo hoje: Windows w UNIX (distribuições Linux, Apple OS X, BSD). SO's desses dois tipos são extremamente diferentes, resolvem problemas de maneiras completamente distintas e têm filosofias de uso bastante conflitantes.

Não vou discorrer detalhadamente sobre essas diferenças aqui pois acho que não cabe neste tópico, mas é bem útil ter em mente que não há como comparar diretamente os dois e escolher um melhor: são bichinhos diferentes, cada um com suas qualidades e defeitos; apontar que um é melhor que o outro sem levar em consideração o contexto onde eles estão sendo utilizados seria burrice.

## Sistema operacional para servidor

A esmagadora maioria dos servidores web rodam Linux, em razão de este ser o sistema operacional mais ubíqua e com maior suporte para rodar aplicações web e por ser completamente livre e de graça. Obviamente existem muitas aplicações rodando em ambientes Windows, principalmente aquelas que usam tecnologias da Microsoft, como por exemplo a plataforma .NET (C#, ASP.NET, VB.NET) que foi feita especialmente pra rodar nesse sistema. Em geral o ambiente Windows pode ser um pouco inóspito pra alguns tipos de plataformas - tente rodar uma aplicação Ruby no Windows sem arrancar alguns tufos de cabelo tentando depurar a torrente de problemas que ocorrem :)

## Sistema operacional para máquina de desenvolvimento

Se você desenvolve aplicações usando tecnologias da Microsoft (.NET por exemplo) não há muita escolha: a solução é usar Windows. Apesar de haver alguns esforços da Microsoft em trazer sua plataforma pra outros sistemas operacionais (como o [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com), lançado essa semana pela Microsoft), só o Windows oferece todo os suporte que você precisa pra desenvolver esse tipo de aplicações.

Se você desenvolve aplicações para iOS ou OS X é pior ainda: você é obrigado a usar um Mac.

Agora, para desenvolvimento em outras tecnologias mais abertas há mais opções. O PHP é um bom exemplo: você pode desenvolver aplicações web usando PHP tanto em sistemas Windows, como UNIX. Qual você vai escolher depende muito de preferência pessoal. Se você prefere ferramentas de linha de comando, normalmente vai optar por UNIX, dado que o ambiente de linha de comando e as ferramentas disponíveis nesse sistema são **muito** superiores às presentes no Windows (um ótimo exemplo são gerenciadores de pacotes: instalar bibliotecas e dependências em sistemas UNIX é extremamente fácil usando ferramentas como Homebrew, APT ou Pacman; já no Windows isso pode se tornar uma tarefa árdua, dado que as ferramentas disponíveis não são tão avançadas e usam uma filosofia bem diferente). Se preferes utilizar IDE's e outras ferramentas visuais existe uma flexibilidade maior, e usar Windows não se torna tão problemático.

Há também uma grande influência da comunidade. Um bom exemplo é o Ruby: a esmagadora maioria dos desenvolvedores Ruby - pra não dizer todos - usam ambientes UNIX (Linux ou OS X). Isso acontece por uma série de fatores: apesar de possível é extremamente problemático rodar aplicações Ruby no Windows; a maioria das ferramentas Ruby usam a linha de comando e são inspiradas nas filosofias do ambiente UNIX. Logo é quase óbvio usar Linux ou OS X  pra desenvolver esse tipo de aplicação.

Apenas a título de ilustração: a maioria dos desenvolvedores que eu conheço usam UNIX - alguma distribuição Linux ou OS X - mas isso é uma realidade do tipo de aplicação que desenvolvo e da comunidade em que estou incluído.

## Dual-boot

Você pode fazer dual-boot em qualquer computador, não precisa de um computador específico para rodar Linux. As distribuições modernas têm ótimo suporte a diversos tipos de hardware e a cada temos mais avanços nesse quesito, então você não deve ter problema nenhum ao rodar uma distribuição Linux em hardwares atuais.