# Abrir arquivo Access no linux

Tags: php, microsoft-access

Por conexão , como eu altero o meu DSN ?

um dos cases na minha classe de conexao que abre arquivo em access

```
case "fatura" :
            $strHost = "";
            $strUser = "";
            $strPass = "";
            $strBase = "";
            $strType = "";
         $strDSN  = "odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=iso-8859-1; DBQ={$strArquivo}; Uid=; Pwd=;";
        //$strDSN  = "odbc:DRIVER=Driver{Easysoft ODBC-ACCESS};charset=iso-8859-1; DBQ={$strArquivo}; Uid=; Pwd=;";
            break;
```

eu tentei alterar o DSN para receber o driver Easysoft ODBC-ACCESS pois o que pesquisei no linux não abre arquivos odbc, mas no primeiro momento sem sucesso, o que poderia ser ?? ou o que estar faltando

A mensagem que exibe é :

```
"RepositorioException: Nao foi possivel conectar ao banco de dados: SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found","location":""}
```

Comment: Este driver Easysoft ODBC-ACCESS , não funciona mais ... pelo que eu pesquisei teria algum,que eu pudesse adicionar no ubuntu , e colocar no meu DSN ?

Answer (score 2):

Acho que a mensagem deixa bem clara que é "file not found":

> SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found

Provavelmente é problema de case-sensitive, em Linux e sistemas baseados em Unix (como Mac OSX), se colocar algo como:

```
 $strArquivo = 'Arquivo.mdb';
```

E na pasta ele estiver assim `arquivo.mdb`, não vai funcionar. Em Windows é case-INsensitive, ou seja em Windows `arquivo.mdb` é igual a `Arquivo.mdb` (não é algo ligado ao PHP é uma questão de sistema operacional).

**Leia isso:** [PHP no linux ou windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60905/3635)

Outro problema pode ser simplesmente que esta apontando um caminho invalido.