# Herança de Interface que está em outra pasta

Tags: php

Como posso implemetar essa `Interface` nas minhas classes?

*class/layout/Header.php*

```
class Header implements Interface {
    private function setHeader()
    {

    }

    public function getHeader()
    {

    }
}
```

*class/interface/Interface.php*

```
interface Interface {
    public function getHeader();
}
```

*class/autoLoad.php*

```
function getClass($class) 
{
    $dir = ['interface', 'layout'];

    foreach ($dir as $row) :
        $files = "class/{$row}/{$class}.php";
        if (file_exists($files)) :
          require_once $files;
        endif;
    endforeach;
}

spl_autoload_register("getClass");
```

*index.php*

```
require_once "class/autoLoad.php";
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Interface' (T_INTERFACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or namespace (T_NAMESPACE) or \ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in C:\xampp\htdocs\class\layout\Header.php on line 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Palavra `Interface` é reservada no PHP**. Você não pode usar esta palavra como nome de classe, namespaces ou afins.

Quando você recebe a mensagem como:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'Interface' (T_INTERFACE)
```

Basta você saber o que o token indicado entre parenteses significa, então no caso você pode ler os tokens em:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Seguindo a lista, o token `T_INTERFACE` represeta os [**Object Interfaces**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), logo você tentou usar a sintaxe `Interface` (criada por ti) e ela não era esperada pelo interpretador do PHP, causando o erro: syntax error, unexpected 'Interface'.

Para resolver basta trocar o nome Interface por um nome que não seja uma palavra reservada, algo como `MainInterface`.

---

**Extra:**

Não se esqueça que se o servidor de produção for Linux, ou Unix-like você não poderá usar includes com nomes assim `include 'src/foo.php';` e arquivos com nome assim `src/Foo.php`, porque linux e unix-like geralmente são case-sensitive.

Mais detalhes sobre rodar PHP em Windows e Linux aqui: [PHP no linux ou windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60906/3635)