# Dúvida com Load do Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um menu que vou utilizar em todas as páginas, então eu quero fazer o carregamento do conteúdo:

Estou fazendo assim:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- This file has been downloaded from Bootsnipp.com. Enjoy! -->
    <title> </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="./css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon/favicon.png">

    <script>
      $("#menu").load("menusistema.html");
    </script>

</head>

<body">

    <div id="menu"></div>

</body>
```

Não está carregando nada, o que poderia está errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode ser que um dos seus arquivos carregados no `<script></script>` está com problema ou você nõa tá linkando certo, aí o arquivo não carrega.

Comment: eu já tentei varias opções e não carrega

Comment: Abra o console do teu navegador, edita a pergunta e cole nela os erros que o console exibiu na sua página.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, adicionei a imagem, veja se consegue me ajudar

Comment: Não precisa postar foto, bastava ter copiado o erro e colado na pergunta. Leia: [**Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/3635) e [**Não postar o seu código ou a sua mensagem de erro**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, então o erro e porque o HTML não esta dentro de um servidor web? aquela mensagem de erro só apareceu porque eu tentei chamar o html no console, mais a tela fica em branco quando abre.

Comment: @itasouza sim, foi o que eu disse na resposta, XMLHttpRequest  (vulgo ajax) só funciona em servidores HTTP e HTTPS ou em extensões para chrome e firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax **não funciona** em protocolo `file://`, tem que usar um servidor `HTTP` como Apache ou Ngnix, a própria mensagem diz isto:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://... Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Traduzindo:

> XMLHttpRequest não pode carregar file://... requisições de origens cruzadas ("diferentes" origens) são apenas suportadas por protocolos: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https e chrome-extension-resource.

Como eu expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/62797/3635

E aqui tem uma explicação do que é Wamp, Xampp e etc:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45564/3635

Então se usa PHP pode instalar:

- http://www.wampserver.com/en/ (windows, apache, php, mysql)
- https://www.apachefriends.org/ (cross-platform, apache, php, mysql, pearl)

Se usa asp.net-mvc então crie um projeto pelo VS e porte os teus .html pra lá.

Answer (score 0):

usa assim

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#menu").load("menusistema.html");
        });
    </script>
```

em vez do seu

```
<script>
      $("#menu").load("menusistema.html");
    </script>
```

e como disse o amigo acima, precisa usar um servidor local, eu uso xampp, e nao o diretorio local, dai funciona certinho